# ImageMagick/etc.: automated removal of unclean edges from scanning?

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection

With a few thousand images like the following one, with complex edges from scanning (first a perfectly regular white one, then a very fuzzy gray/black'ish one), is there a good algorithm to figure out the coordinates of the area-to-keep? In the below example, going clockwise from the north-western corner, the optimal coordinates would be:

- 121,18
- 1934,18
- 1934,1312
- 121,1312

So that from this input image...

[image: sample image]

... can be cropped to remove anything tinted red, as shown here:

[image]

To clarify, I do know how to use ImageMagick or other tools to crop to that area. What I'm not sure about is how to figure out how to get to those above numbers? Do you just binarize the image and then go left to right until you hit "white" for the first time, then do the same from top to bottom, right to left and bottom to top? Or is there some library, script, etc. which already does that for you?

Comment: Please show the cropping, not the coordinates.

Comment: Added another image showing the cropping, thanks Yves!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use vertical and horizontal projections of the image. By a simple detection of the highest transition, you easily find the limit between the background and the paper.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that looks very fancy! What is a "projection"? And am I understanding correctly that the dip in the y-axis around the middle of the x-axis represents the crease in the middle between the two pages whereas the two dips with the green arrows represent the left and right page edges?

Answer (score 2):

Your image has a border of white surrounding a border of black. So you can do two fuzzy -trim processes after padding with the appropriate color to ensure it goes all around the image. So in ImageMagick 6, it would be

Input:

[image]

```
convert book.jpg -bordercolor white -border 1 -fuzz 55% -trim +repage -bordercolor black -border 1 -trim +repage book_trimmed.jpg
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I upvoted this, too, because it works wonderfully with the kind of JPEG file I posted here, which many people will have. Unfortunately I need to operate on the original TIFFs, where removing the black border doesn't work at all, so I'll have to go with Yves' method.